# C# WPF Hyperlink Mailto: Body will not be printed when using binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mailto

I try to use the  Tag in C# WPF to build a link that openes the standard email client.

This is my WPF Code:

```
<TextBlock>
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="mailto:example@stackoverflow.com?subject=SubjectExample&amp;body=BodyExample" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
Click here
</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

This works so far very fine. Now i want to make it a little more dynamically, so i tried to bind a variable with all necessary information:

```
<TextBlock>
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding MyValue}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
Click here
</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

The Public Value MyValue looks like this:

```
public string MyValue{
get { return "mailto:" + myEmail + "?subject=" + mySubject + "&amp;body=TEST"; }
```

Everything works fine except the Body Text. "TEST" should be printed but it isnt. It has been printed in my first try without binding but not in this case

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tested the value passed is the entire `string`? Try putting a converter on that `Binding` and see what is the value that you get from it. You then should see if the subject is somehow affecting your string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to escape the values using the `Uri.EscapeDataString` method:

```
public string MyValue
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format("mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body=TEST",
        Uri.EscapeDataString(myEmail),
        Uri.EscapeDataString(mySubject));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works with one change: Somehow it is not possible to use the string value for the mail adress in Uri. So i had to put this variable directly into string like this: "mailto:" + email + "?subject={0}&body={1}"